# Magento 2 - Fix "Please enter a value greater than or equal to NaN." for input type date

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, customization

I need to add a date input field to my contact site, so that users can select a date when we can call them back. I filled the attribute `min` with the date of today, to prohibit the user from selecting a date from the past.

But if I try to submit I get "Please enter a value greater than or equal to NaN."

[image]

I figured out that this is a bug in the old jquery version which magento 2 is using. They are still using jQuery 1 even when there is already jQuery 3.

What is the best way to replace the jQuery version for the contact site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **minDate** in your jquery

```
 <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="" class="datepicker">

 <script> 
 require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
             dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             yearRange: '2010:2025',
             showMonthAfterYear: false,
              minDate: new Date(),

        }) 
 }); 
</script>
```

if you are using ui-component then use below code

You can set this field in your ui-component

```
<field name="date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Date</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="minDate" xsi:type="string">new Date()+ 1</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!! :)

Comment: happy to hear it helps you :)